# Click event after toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to switch between two buttons(span) - (one element active when the other is not and vice versa).

The problem here is that primary element never actually looses the bind, even though i remove the class from it. The same thing happens to other element, except that effect is the opposite.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="ch1">First</span>
<br />
<span id="ch2" class="action">Second</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;    
}

.action {
cursor:pointer;
font-size:14px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.action').on('click',function(){

        $('#ch1,#ch2').toggleClass('action');

    });
```

> **FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/n2WUn/**

Comment: Try `$('#ch1,#ch2').on('click',function(){` - http://jsfiddle.net/6C2Uc/

Comment: @Vega this is cool, but i also want to remove class from other element.

Comment: Yes it should toggleClass on elements in selector. Did you try that fiddle link?

Comment: Yea :) but it does not. Both links are clickable

Comment: Check @David Thomas's solution

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly.. I think I got it now. Corrected my answer just for clarity..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using delegation, attaching the `on()` method to a parent element of those upon which you wish to act, and using a selector to test for the element:

```
$('body').on('click', '.action', function () {
    $('#ch1,#ch2').toggleClass('action');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n2WUn/3/).

The way this works is that the named event (`'click'`) bubbles to an ancestor element, the target of the event is checked against the selector (`'.action'`) and, if it matches the selector the callback function is executed.

Typically, you should use the closest non-changing element that's present in the DOM at the moment of event-binding (which in your case is the `body` element, but in most web-pages will be another element within the page).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
$('body').on('click', '.action', function(){
    $('#ch1,#ch2').toggleClass('action');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is working : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/n2WUn/4/). `.on` method will work on parent reference.

Answer (score 0):

this work well.

```
$(function(){
    $('.action').bind('click',function(){
         $('#ch1,#ch2').toggleClass('action');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please tell me how is this different from what had posted in OP? except for using `.bind` instead of `.on`.

Comment: Wouldn't this bind the handler only to the element that has class='action' on load?